# Prove that $(\neg p \wedge \neg q) \vee (p \wedge q) \equiv (\neg p \vee q) \wedge (\neg q \vee p)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Prove that $(\neg p \wedge \neg q) \vee (p \wedge q) \equiv (\neg p \vee q) \wedge (\neg q \vee p)$.

I need to prove it by using equivalent sentences.

Comment: Where did you get stuck? What did you try?

Comment: truth table is one way to do it

Comment: Yes , but i need to prove it by using equivalent sentences.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. You should add your additional requirement into the question using the [edit] feature (including what you tried, of course)

Comment: Just use the distribution rule, and note that $\sim p\lor p$ and $\sim q\lor q$ are just $T$ and can be removed.

Comment: @GPX Please change the title by yourself, it's not edited by me, i just changed the question in the main body

Comment: @GPX Sorry that the original answer is not right, which is corrected a little to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a table of truth you can prove that:

(1) w $\vee$ (p $\wedge$ q) ≡ (w $\vee$ p) $\wedge$ (w $\vee$ q)

Hint: use w = (~p ∧ ~q).

Here follows the steps

(2) (~p ∧ ~q) ∨ (p ∧ q) ≡ ((~p ∧ ~q) $\vee$ p) $\wedge$ ((~p ∧ ~q) $\vee$ q)

Using (1) we can say that

(~p ∧ ~q) $\vee$ p ≡ (~p $\vee$ p) $\wedge$ (~q $\vee$ p)

as (~p $\vee$ p) its a tautology,

(3)(~p ∧ ~q) $\vee$ p ≡ (~q $\vee$ p)

using (3) and (2):

(4) (~p ∧ ~q) ∨ (p ∧ q) ≡ (~q $\vee$ p) $\wedge$ ((~p ∧ ~q) $\vee$ q)

Using (1) we can say that

(~p ∧ ~q) $\vee$ q ≡ (~p $\vee$ q) $\wedge$ (~q $\vee$ q)

as (~q $\vee$ q) its a tautology,

(5)(~p ∧ ~q) $\vee$ q ≡ (~p $\vee$ q)

Using (4) and (5)

(6)(~p ∧ ~q) ∨ (p ∧ q) ≡ (~q $\vee$ p) $\wedge$ (~p $\vee$ q)

And there you go

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have this in your arsenal, try using a "first-inside outside-last" distribution for the propositions. Then simplify.

That is, think of it like addition and multiplication:

$(a+b) \cdot (c+d) = (a \cdot c) + (a \cdot d) + (b \cdot c) + (b \cdot d)$.

If that isn't allowed, try using truth tables as a simple way of approaching it.

Answer (score 0):

**Propositional Calculus**
Use de Morgan's rules. Start like this:
$$(\neg p \wedge \neg q) \vee (p \wedge q) \equiv (\neg p \vee (p \wedge q)) \wedge (\neg q \vee (p \wedge q))$$
Now apply them again inside the parentheses and remove tautologies. Then you're done.

---

**Truth table**
You can make a truth table with two variables and two outcomes. It will have four rows, so it's not too much work.
The start will look like this:

$$\begin{array}{cc|c|c}
p & q & (\neg p \wedge \neg q) \vee (p \wedge q) & (\neg p \vee q) \wedge (\neg q \vee p) \\
\hline
T & T & &\\
T & F & &\\
F & T & &\\
F & F & &
\end{array}$$
The statement then says that the missing two columns are identical.

Answer (score 0):

$(\neg p\wedge\neg q)\vee(p\wedge q)=\neg((p\vee q)\wedge\neg(p\wedge q))=\neg((\neg p\wedge q)\vee(p\wedge\neg q))=(p\vee\neg q)\wedge(\neg p\vee q)$